# Kullback-Leibler $KL(p,q)\neq KL(q,p)$

Tags: probability, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I'm doing a course of Artificial Intelligence and in my homework I must to provide a counter example to show that the Kullback-Leibler distance is not a symmetric function of its arguments:

$$
KL(p,q)\neq KL(q,p)
$$

Could someone please help me to resolve this exercise because I don't understand.

Comment: Just take two Bernoulli random variable with parameters $p=\frac 12$ and $q=\frac 13$.